# How to make an RC mixer with the arduino

Tags: arduino-nano, pwm, remote-control

I want to make a RC mixer mixing two channels of a receiver.

What I have: a delta model plane, two servos, a receiver and a Arduino Nano.

So I'd like to mix the aileron (two channels) with the elevator(one channel).

EDIT: What I've done: I read the input of the receiver and wrote it to the servos. The problem: The servo stutters and the arduino displays false inputs.

```
int pin = A0;
int pin1 = A1;
unsigned long duration;
unsigned long dur;

unsigned long duration2;
unsigned long dur2;

#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;
Servo myservo2;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(9);
}

void loop()
{
  duration = pulseIn(pin, HIGH);
  dur = duration;
  Serial.println(dur);
  myservo.writeMicroseconds(dur);
  delay(50);
//  duration2 = pulseIn(pin1, HIGH);
//  dur2 = duration2-980/4-200;
//  Serial.println(dur2);
//  myservo2.write(dur2);
}
```

Comment: Apparently no access to google?

Comment: Can you give me a good instruction how to do that???

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" is a reason for downvoting. Please show us what you tried and how far you got.

Comment: That is NOT how we do it. Flying a delta plane should not require anything between the receiver and servos, you just have to program the radio correctly. Almost all the popular RC radios today have built-in delta mixing. The SAFE system planes from E-Flite do the mixing on-board, but it doesn't require any additional hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use long for values from pulseIn, using int will be sufficient.

Your code is not complete, at least there is a missing '}' at the end of setup.

The slower the baud rate (9600) actually the more it interferes with timing code, to a point.  PWM is all timing code.  I would suggest 57,600.

You never set the servos to any pins.  And is using Servo lib needed? I have always used [analogWrite](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/analogWrite) with no problems.

You are not using parenthesis on your math (currently commented). It will not give you the result you expect. But you are somewhat on the right track, subtract 1500 from each pulse read, that will give you -/+ range. How you mix that depends on how your radio is setup (servo reversing, which channel is which). Keep in mind ailerons is 1 channel, so left aileron = -rightAileron.  Elevator up = that + elevator.  so;

aileronLeft = airleronChannel + elevatorChannel
aileronRight = -airleronChannel + elevatorChannel

You do realize this a [$3 part](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__6321__TURNIGY_V_Tail_Mixer_Ultra_small.html)?

update: I have always used analogWrite, but I also always use good equipment. I see cautions that cheapo servos might be damaged with analogWrite. You can read more [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=5701.0). It has always worked for me.

Comment: How to disable the bad stuttering??  :( And can you say me how to use a servo with analogWrite()? Thank you!